# Showing the following two integrals are equal

Tags: calculus

I would like to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+x}} dt = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}-2t\sqrt{x}}dt,\quad  x>0.$$

I haven't been able to have very much success with this integral. So far I have made a couple observations:

1) I think there is an obvious step of completing the square on the RHS.

2) The presence of the 2 and a Gaussian like integral suggests to me that there is some way to integrate the RHS by extending the limits of integration to all of $\mathbb{R}$ and then using a trick similar to how a Gaussian is integrated using polar coordinates.

Aside from these observations, I have made no progress. In particular, I am find the $\sqrt{t+x}$ term on the LHS hard to be especially difficult to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $t=(s+\sqrt x)^2-x$ in the first integral, then we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+x}}\,dt&=\int_0^\infty \frac{2(s+\sqrt x)e^{-(s+\sqrt x)^2+x}}{s+\sqrt x}\,ds\tag 1\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-s^2-2s\sqrt x}\,ds\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-2t\sqrt x}\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

The OP had asked a good question in a comment after the initial post regarding the implication of the alternative substitution $s+\sqrt x=-\sqrt{t+x}$ instead of $s+\sqrt x =\sqrt{t+x}$ as used in arriving at $(1)$.

So, let's see what happens in this alternative substitution.  Instead of $(1)$, we would have obtained

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+x}}\,dt&=\int_{-2\sqrt x}^{-\infty} \frac{2(s+\sqrt x)e^{-(s+\sqrt x)^2+x}}{-(s+\sqrt x)}\,ds\tag 2\\\\
&=2\int_{-\infty}^{-2\sqrt x}e^{-(s+\sqrt x)^2+x}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Then, substituting $s=-2\sqrt x-t$ into $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+x}}\,dt&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-(t+\sqrt x)^2+x}\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-2t\sqrt x}\,dt
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Sorry, I am having some trouble following these steps. I have two questions. The first one is immediately after the substitution, how does $e^{-t}$ become $e^{-(s+\sqrt{x})^{2}}$ instead of $e^{-(s+\sqrt{x})^{2}+x}$. The second one is that when $t = 0$, $s$ could be either $0$ or $-2\sqrt{x}$, how do you decide what the lower limit of integration becomes after the substitution?

Comment: I'm with you JessicaK.  I am not (yet) convinced by this derivation.  *Mathematica* shows that both sides evaluate to $\sqrt{\pi } e^x \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$.

Comment: @JessicaK I've edited to correct the typo, which led to an error.

Comment: Yes.... they *are* equal, as I (and *Mathematica*) derived explicitly.

Comment: @JessicaK I've added a new section to show that the choice of sign on the square root in the initial substitution is irrelevant.  Either choice leads to the same result!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you very much. Perhaps I accepted it a bit early but the current answer completely addresses everything I was unsure about.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased to hear this helped.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much of an answer, as showing something kind of nice.
Let's let both these functions be represented as $f(x)$.

Now, the first is $f(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t-x}}dt$.

Then, we see that $f(0) = t^{-1/2}*e^{-t}dt = \sqrt{\pi}$, as this is the gamma function.

Now, the second function is $g(x) = 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-2t\sqrt{x}}dt$, and at $g(0)$, this becomes $2 \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ which also happens to be $\sqrt{\pi}$, as it is one of the steps in solving the gamma function.

Therefore, there is at least one point where they are equal :)

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding where $g(x)$ comes from.

Comment: @JessicaK, my bad. I skipped a step and combined some stuff that didn't go together and I mixed up my $x$'s and $t$'s

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, so please don't down-vote this.  Nevertheless, here's how this problem can be solved using computer algebra.  In *Mathematica*:

```
Assuming[Re[x] > 0, 
  Integrate[Exp[-t]/Sqrt[t + x], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]] == 
 Assuming[Re[x] > 0, 
  2 Integrate[Exp[-t^2 - 2 t Sqrt[x]], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

(* True *)

Answer (score 0):

transform the integral on the left:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t+x}} dt =e^x\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(t+x)}}{\sqrt{t+x}} dt 
$$
now with $u^2=t+x$, so $dt=2udu$
$$
=2e^x\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du 
$$
now the integral on the right:
$$
2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}-2t\sqrt{x}}dt =  2e^x\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(t-\sqrt{x})^2}dt
$$
now with $u=t-\sqrt{x}$ this becomes:
$$
=  2e^x\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du
$$

Answer (score 0):

I know that an answer has been accepted already, but I'd like to present an alternate solution nonetheless.

We have the equation as follows:

$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-t}\over \sqrt{t+x}}dt = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-2t\sqrt x}dt$$

First, we multiply both sides by $e^{-x}$.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t-x} * (t+x)^{-1/2} dt = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2-2t\sqrt x - x}dt$$

Which simplifies to

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-(t+x)} * (t+x)^{-1/2} dt = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-(t+\sqrt x)^2}dt$$

On the LHS, we do a substitution $u = t+x, du = dt$ and the lower bound becomes $x$. On the RHS, we do a substitution $s = t + \sqrt x, ds = dt$ and the lower bound becomes $\sqrt x$.

$$\int_x^\infty e^{-(u)} * (u)^{-1/2} du = 2\int_{\sqrt x}^\infty e^{-(s^2)}ds$$

Note that these are equal to

$$ \Gamma (1/2) - \int_0^x e^{-(u)} * (u)^{-1/2} du = \Gamma (1/2) -2\int_{0}^{\sqrt x}e^{-(s^2)}ds$$

Therefore it suffices to take find if the second and fourth term are equal; Simplifying and changing the variable again on the LHS with $p^2 = u, du = 2pdp$, the bounds change to $0$ and $\sqrt x$ we get

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt x} e^{-(p^2)} * (p^2)^{-1/2} * 2p dp = 2\int_{0}^\sqrt x e^{-(s^2)}ds$$

Which simplifies to

$$2\int_{0}^{\sqrt x} e^{-(p^2)} dp = 2\int_{0}^\sqrt x e^{-(s^2)}ds$$

Therefore, the two integrals are equal!